# I'm having issues with camel http4 endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

Spring context:

```
<bean id="customRouteA" class="com.xxx.CustomRouteABean" />

<camelContext id="solr" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:topic:agent" />
        <to uri="bean:customRouteA"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Java code:

```
public class CustomRouteABean {

@EndpointInject(uri = "http4://localhost/camel-route-test.php")
ProducerTemplate producer;

public void processMessage(@Body String message) {
    ...
}
}
```

Keeps getting error:

```
2085 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customRouteA' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.apache.camel.spring.GenericBeansException: Error post processing bean: customRouteA; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: http4://localhost/camel-route-test.php?bridgeEndpoint=true due to: null
```

I have another bean has the same setup works just fine, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

And you have camel-http4 and its dependent JARs on the classpath?

Comment: yes, it's in maven pom.xml,

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>

Comment: yes, it's in maven pom.xml,

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

I tried to put the uri directly in XML route and it doesn't complain:

    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:topic:cd.search.agent" />
        <to uri="http4://localhost/camel-route-test.php"/>
    </route>

I have other routes, but they shouldn't affect each other, right?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It turned out http4 doesn't work very well in my setup, when I switch to http, it works. Not sure why yet.